# Detect when object really removed from stage

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to detect whether object was definitely removed from stage. I check many answers here and in other places & do not know how to be noticed that object was really removed from stage (i mean it is no longer displayed on the stage).
The code below is my last test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="50%" backgroundColor="gray" id="c1">
        <mx:Canvas id="cChild" backgroundColor="black" width="20" height="20" 
        left="20" top="20" 
        removedFromStage="trace('removed from stage ' + event.target)" 
        removed="trace('removed ' + event.target)">
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="50%" backgroundColor="white"  id="c2">
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Button label="add child" click="c2.addChild(c1)" />
    <mx:Button label="add child2" click="addChild(c1)" />
</mx:Application>
```

I do not understand what i found at console output:

```
removed MainFlex0.c1.cChild.border
  - before click 'add child'
removed from stage MainFlex0.c1.cChild
removed MainFlex0.c2.c1.cChild.border
  - after click 'add child', before 'add child2'
removed from stage MainFlex0.c2.c1.cChild
removed MainFlex0.c1.cChild.border
  - after click 'add child2'
```

Is any condition i can check and be sure that object is REALLY "about to be removed from stage"?

Saram

Comment: If anyone read this question, please check whether at your platform first REMOVED event is also triggered at start without any reason.

Answer (score 0):

`removedFromStage` is called just before the item is removed from the stage. If you don't do anything in that event handler the element will be removed.

Comment: As you can see event was called two times but item is still on the stage.

Comment: When you call addChild to add something to another container on stage, it removes that child from its parent this will trigger the events. So the child is actually removed from stage for a brief time and then added to the other container.

Comment: I understand the backgroud of stage manager. The question is, how to be noticed, that object was REALLY removed from stage. I need to colaborate with not my code, and do action if object was removed from the stage permanently, not internaly by stage manager or stg.
btw. notice, that at the begining of my example REMOVED event is triggered without any reason - is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !c1.stage ){
// it is not on stage
}
```